ssh failed with kex_exchange_identification: read: connection reset
i'm on a win10 and want to ssh to a remote linux server, but got the following failture...how can i make a further try?
(i checked /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow on server and nothing wrong)
ssh -v name@ip

OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to server.ip.xxx.xxx [server.ip.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myname/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
kex_exchange_identification: write: Connection reset

